# iOS Tutorial not working in iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, ios5.1

I have completely finished this tutorial, which does not seem to work for me.

http://zaldzbugz.posterous.com/how-to-mark-or-get-the-highlighted-string-ins

This is a great tutorial showing how to copy/paste content from a uiwebview.I downloaded the source and ran it on my ios simulator, but i can't get the text i selected. As a result i only get an empty string.

Does anyone know why it's running anymore?
I'm using iOS SDK 5.1

Sincerely,

Zoli

**Additional info**
using iOS 5.0 simulator it's working, using iOS 5.1 It's not.

Comment: What error is displayed?

Comment: use NSLog to isolate the problem and give more informations about the errors.

Comment: no error. at the bottom of the tutorial page you see, you should see an alert pop up with the selected text as a content and "Oh yeah" for the button's text. for me a content is empty. I also NSLog the highlightedString, but it's empty. the debugger says it's value is @""

Comment: it is working fine with me, are you sure you selected any text from the webview?

Comment: yes, the text is highlighted when i push the "get highlighted string" method

Comment: i just modified the description. with iOS 5.0 simulator it's working, but it does not work with iOS simulator 5.1

Comment: oddly enough it's working now. i don't know what the reason was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a really interesting error. After installing ios5.0 simulator it worked both in 5.1 an 5.0 too.